# Excel VBA to insert line until text is matched

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I've got an Excel file that should have the text 'UNK' as the first 3 letters of cell A10 (I don't care what comes after the UNK). If it does NOT match this text, I need to insert a blank line at the top of the Excel file. For some reason my code is not evaluating correctly and I'm not sure why. I'm using:

```
If Left(A10, 3) <> "UNK" Then
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End If
```

As you might be able to tell, I'm a novice with this type of code. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? It loops until either A10 is blank or it finds UNK.

```
  Do While Range("A10") <> ""
    If Left(Range("A10"), 3) <> "UNK" Then
      Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Else
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Worked great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this to:

```
If Left(Range("A10"), 3) <> "UIC" Then
    Range("A1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End If
```

Comment: Hm, maybe I didn't make my post as clear as I could have. After I insert a line, I need to re-evaluate and make sure that A10 starts with "UNK". If it STILL does not, keep adding blank lines to the top of the file.